# How to Making Telerik RadGrid Responsive With jQuery FooTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, responsive-design, telerik-grid

There are two questions regards this requirement:

1- I am trying to open a user control in edit form mod , in user controls i have used footable  (reference Link themergency.com/footable/) with asp gridview. footable functionality not working with in user control, if I simply open  that control at another page other than in line edit form user control in radgrid, footable workng correctly , is there any conflict between telerik and other jquery plugins ...?

2 - I want to make Telerik radgrid behave as footable  (refrence Link http://themergency.com/footable-demo/demo.htm) please help if possible

Comment: I am having the same problem with a radgrid in a user control that I have added to the nestedviewtemplate of the parent radgrid.